# Can I use Referencing functions and UI controls such as 'Microsoft.Solutions.ArmApiControl' in the uiFormDefinition of an Azure Template Spec?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I'm creating a Template Spec using Bicep, which works fine. Adding a custom UI to the Template Spec using a uiFormDefinition file also works. However, when I try to use the control 'Microsoft.Solutions.ArmApiControl' in the UI definition, it fails with the error `Failed to create element of type: 'Microsoft.Solutions.ArmApiControl' named 'sqlCapabilities'`. I found that I can get rid of the error by removing all referencing functions from the `path` property, like this:

```
{
    "name": "sqlCapabilities",
    "type": "Microsoft.Solutions.ArmApiControl",
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/subscriptions/34d76722-9b63-464d-b742-11bf072d1fc1/providers/Microsoft.Sql/locations/westeurope/capabilities?api-version=2021-11-01"
    }
}
```

... but that doesn't actually seems to do anything. (And even if this would work the element wouldn't be very useful without referencing functions.)

While reading the documentation, I noticed there are two sandboxes in the Azure Portal for developing uiFormDefinition files:

1. https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_CreateUIDef/FormSandboxBlade (titled "Form view Sandbox"), which is linked to from the [Create portal form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-specs-create-portal-forms) page of the ARM template documentation using the shortlink https://aka.ms/form/sandbox.
2. https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_CreateUIDef/SandboxBlade (titled "Create UI Definition Sandbox"), which is linked to from the [Create portal interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/create-uidefinition-overview) page of the Azure Managed Applications Documentation.

They look similar, but they use different schemas: the UI Definition sandbox uses `https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/0.1.2-preview/CreateUIDefinition.MultiVm.json#` and the Form sandbox uses `https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2021-09-09/uiFormDefinition.schema.json`. The Form sandbox also has a few additional options such as the ability to specify the "Package Type" and "CUID".

Both sandboxes have a list documenting UI elements, which both point to the same destination: the Azure Managed Applications documentation.

The thing is: when I use the "Create UI Definition Sandbox" the 'Microsoft.Solutions.ArmApiControl' UI element works fine, even when using referencing functions like `location()`. However, I can't use the resulting file with the Template Spec: it attaches OK but when trying to deploy the Template Spec in the Portal I get this error: `Invalid UIFormDefinition Schema. Click here to fallback to default experience.`

Using referencing functions and/or 'Microsoft.Solutions.ArmApiControl' in the "Form view Sandbox" results in the problems mentioned at the beginning of this question.

Experimenting further, it looks like all functions work in both sandboxes, with the exception of referencing functions like `location()`, `resourceGroup()` or`subscription()`: those only appear to work in the UI definition sandbox. The same applies to some UI elements.

Perhaps I missed it, but I wasn't able to find where this behavior is documented.

Is there a way to use the referencing functions and Microsoft.Solutions.ArmApiControl in a form definition for a Template Spec? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - you can do what you want, take a look at this: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-governance-and-management/using-azure-templatespecs-with-a-custom-ui/ba-p/3586173

Long version, there are 2 schemas/formats for portal ui (as you discovered), there is an "old" version `CreateUIDefinition.MultiVm.json` and a newer version `uiFormDefinition.schema.json` - the newer version is largely a superset of the old version... i.e. it supports all the old stuff and has some new stuff.  This distinction is not well documented yet.

templateSpecs only support the "newer" schema.

That help?

Comment: Hi, thanks, that has indeed helped to get me going! In addition to what you answered here (but what became clear to me from the code you linked to in your blog post), none of the referencing functions (such as subscription() or location() ) work in the new schema, with the exception of steps(). Fortunately, steps() in combination with the Microsoft.Common.ResourceScope element are an adequate replacement.

Comment: Good clarification - the "functionality" is there, but the way you use it has changed quite a bit...  hopefully this will find its way to the official docs.